# Brew Install MySQL, El Capitan Request Loop

Tags: mysql, localhost, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

During this step of brew install mysql:

```
==> Pouring mysql-5.7.9.el_capitan.bottle.1.tar.gz
```

This keeps happening to my log every 10 seconds:

```
Log:  
12/8/15 2:54:58.681 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld[38555]) Service could not initialize: Unable to set current working directory. error = 2: No such file or directory, path = /usr/local/mysql: 15B42: xpcproxy + 12028 [1353][19011403-4854-3CCD-9FCF-49C36302EB40]: 0x2
12/8/15 2:54:58.681 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

Now, I can run the sql server but it's still making these requests and I don't know how to fix it.  Even when I stop the server this request keeps occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem, seems you have installed mysql not from homebrew.
Deleting this `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist` and restart PC solved this problem.